# Why does manually computing index of character in string return -1?

Tags: javascript, return-value, indexof

**Requirement**: The function should return the first index in the word at which the character exists or -1 if the character is not found. Do not use the String.indexOf() function.

**Example**: `stringIndexOf('awesome', 'e') // returns 2`

The problem is, my code keeps returning -1:

```
function stringIndexOf(word, char) {
  let index = 1
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] === char) {
      index = i
    }
  }
  return -1
}
console.log(stringIndexOf('awesome', 'e'));
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps `return index` immediately once the match is found.

Comment: you are returning -1  with `return -1`  you should `return index`

Comment: ( (word, char) => word.search(char))('awesome', 'e');

Answer (score 1):

You're code keeps returning -1 because at the end of `stringIndexOf` you return -1.

```
function stringIndexOf(word, char) {
  let index = 1
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] === char) {
      index = i
    }
  }
  return -1 // <---------- :(
}
console.log(stringIndexOf('awesome', 'e'));
```

Should be:

```
function stringIndexOf(word, char) {
  // This can start at -1 so you can return
  // -1 in the case that word[i] never equaled char,
  // meaning the char does not exist in the word.
  let index = -1

  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] === char) {
      index = i
    }
  }
  return index
}
console.log(stringIndexOf('awesome', 'e'));
```

Comment: How about [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)ing out of the `for` loop in order to not always go *full cycle*?

Comment: That would be more efficient. I was attempting to make only the required edits to meet their requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use a second "return" sentence or save the returning value before the function's last line.

Option 1:

```
function stringIndexOf(word, char) {
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] === char) {
      return i
    }
  }
  return -1
}
```

Option 2:

```
function stringIndexOf(word, char) {
  let index;
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] === char) {
      index = i
    }
  }
  if (index == undefined) {
    index = -1;
  }
  return index;
}
```

You can avoid this last if statement and just give "-1" value on the first line to "index" variable.

A bit of extra advice:
Although word[i] works, it's better to use word.charAt(i) -it's the proper method for strings, [ ] is better for Arrays.

Comment: One neither wants to leave a `for` loop via `return` nor does one want to always fully iterate the `for` loop. How about using a `while` based loop or a [`break` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) within the `for` loop?

Comment: Isn't "break" just as bad as "return" inside a loop? A while loop would be better, but I didn't want to mess a lot their code in case it made it harder to understand. :)

Comment: A `break` is totally valid (there is even a `continue`). But in order to not hurt anybody I suggested both ... *"How about using a __while__ based loop or a break ..."* ... of cause I personally prefer `while`

Answer (score 0):

Besides the obvious mistake of always letting the function return `-1`, which can be fixed as others already suggested, there is an approach, free of `indexOf`, which in addition uses neither a `for` nor a `while` statement but makes use of [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) instead ...

```js
function stringIndexOf(str, search) {
  let index = -1;

  search = String(search);
  const result = String(str).split(search, 2);

//if ((result.length === 2) && (search.length === 1)) {
  if ((result.length === 2) && (search.length >= 1)) {

    index = result[0].length;
  }
  return index;
}

console.log(
  "stringIndexOf('awesome', 'e')",
  stringIndexOf('awesome', 'e')
);
console.log(
  "stringIndexOf('awesome', 'we')",
  stringIndexOf('awesome', 'we')
);
console.log(
  "stringIndexOf('awesome', 'awe')",
  stringIndexOf('awesome', 'awe')
);
console.log(
  "stringIndexOf('awesome', 'some')",
  stringIndexOf('awesome', 'some')
);
console.log(
  "stringIndexOf('awesome', 'awesomeness')",
  stringIndexOf('awesome', 'awesomeness')
);
console.log(
  "stringIndexOf('awesome', '4')",
  stringIndexOf('awesome', '4')
);
console.log(
  "stringIndexOf('awesome', '')",
  stringIndexOf('awesome', '')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```